# Setting size of an image in PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I am trying to set size of an image in PHP but it's not working..

```
echo "<img src=".$media."width=200 height=200";
```

$media is the src link. Without the width and height attributes, it works perfectly well. I think that `200` must be enclosed in double quotations but I am unable to do that. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`width` is currently concatenated with your file name. Use:

```
echo '<img src="'.$media.'" width="200" height="200" />';
```

The `/>` closing tag is necessary to correctly render your image element.
The quotes around tag names are recommended. Omitting these quotes will only cause issues when:

1. The attribute value contain spaces, *or*
2. You forgot to add a space after the attribute value

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative, just for kicks:

```
echo <<<EOL
<img src="{$media}" width="200" height="200" />
EOL;
```

aka a [HEREDOC](http://php.net/heredoc).

Comment: lol. Annyway, as you know, this is not the point. The point is that your answer is right and I don't understand why someone downvote it.

Comment: Some people throw out downvotes on opinion, rather than fact. I only ever downvote on things that are outright wrong. Doesn't bother me either way.

Answer (score 1):

That is because that is not proper HTML.

In your code you'd get something like:

```
<img src=image.jpgwidth=200 height=200
```

And what you need is:

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

So do:

```
echo '<img src="' . $media . '" width="200" height="200" />';
```

Comment: And honestly, you *should* quote your attributes... but if you don't want to refactor your entire site/app, just add a space before `width` in your original line of code and close the tag:
`echo "<img src=".$media." width=200 height=200 />";`
It will work fine in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

`echo '<img src="' . $media . '" width="200" height="200" />';`

Comment: Most browsers can figure out where a closing bracket should go, but this returns a well-formatted HTML string that won't make a browser go barf in the morning.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to make it work with the following code

```
echo "<img src=\"".$media."\" width=200 height=200>";
```

Comment: Close your image tag to have proper HTML. And put quotes around the width and height values and add a unit such as px to it.

Comment: HTML image tags don't have to be closed. You're thinking of XHTML.

Comment: @Jules the px is not necessary, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#h-13.7.1 and  http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#h-6.6

Comment: @Juhana: Nevertheless XHTML has many advantages over HTML and its usage is way better practise. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp
Kibbee: I agree, but once you notice all the different ways browsers interpret these values it's way easier to specify them and make sure there's no doubt.